# Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" in all of our site pages as Javascript Error in Google Console

Tags: javascript, console, syntax-error

This seems to come up as an issue occasionally but I can't find a solution or reference that matches our issue.

Google Developer Console is reporting this as a red X error on every page on our site, would love some help figuring out what is causing it and where/how to eliminate it.  Is there a problem with the jquery.min.js 3.51 that is being called?

Here is the readout of the console error in every page on our site.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at b (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:formatted:48)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:formatted:152)
    at text script (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:formatted:3940)
    at jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:formatted:3750
    at l (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:formatted:3762)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:formatted:3899)
```

If I need to provide more details please let me know what would help troubleshoot this.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKB1d.png)

Thank you!

Comment: It's impossible to help with this question w/o seeing your page source. I have a few suspects:
1 - seems like your pages making AJAX (XHR) request, and instead of JSON pick HTML (for example 404) - so look up your network.

2 - there is an error on your page - non-closed tag or typo.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd be missing something like a }, ], etc. Hard to tell without code. But that's usually what the error is when you get a syntax error. It's going to be in your code because jquery is tested.

Comment: Thanks for the input.... could it be an issue in our html, page, or template (header), etc that contains the calls to the jQuery?  like an unclosed or missing open/close []{} somewhere on the overall page?